# Website always having DNS problems

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I moved my website from shared hosting to VPS. When it was in shared hosting all I did is updated my name servers whereas now I got my own VPS server and I used one of my domain `sjdpublishing.com` as the primary domain for my VPS.

I created nameservers as `ns1.sjdpublishing.com` and `ns2.sjdpublishing.com` and then my actual website is `creativeproperty.com.au` which are pointing to `ns1.sjdpublishing.com` and `ns2.sjdpublishing.com`

I am having repeated problems with my domain `creativeproperty.com.au` a few weeks back I had a problem which was resolved by flushing DNS and later I got similar problem which was not resolved by flushing DNS, I posted a question here and someone answered me to go to Network Settings in my MAC OSX and remove the IP as in my MAC terminal `nslookup creativeproperty.com.au` points to my router IP and I fixed this problem

Now many of my clients were complaining that they are having same troubles accessing my website. I don't know whether its to flush DNS or change network settings or other issues. Can anyone please check my domain `creativeproperty.com.au` and `sjdpublishing.com` are having correct records or not and also can anyone tell me the best solution for this issue?

Comment: if you just want it to work, I suggest using your registrar's DNS servers rather than maintaining your own. Godaddy includes this service for free.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you don't have root nameserver host records for your domain sjdpublishing.com for ns1 and ns2.

The instructions will vary based on registrar, I could not find information specific to crazydomains (the registrar for sjdpublishing) but in essence there should be a page where you can add HOSTS of nameservers, where you can enter ns1.sjdpublishing.com AND an IP address. This is called a nameserver glue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records

Here are the instructions for GoDaddy, maybe you can find something similar that matches in your registrar's account page for the domain.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/668/registering-your-own-nameservershosts

Edit: I found a youtube video that shows how to add the glue for Crazydomains:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnZlAoAUnVg

Add ns1 and ns2.sjdpublishing.com with the IP of 198.38.89.224

#### SOA Record for sjdpublishing.com

```
$TTL    300

@   IN  SOA ns1.sjdpublishing.com. housesboughtfast.hotmail.com. (
            2013090501
            1200
            300
            604800
            3600 )

sjdpublishing.com.              IN NS   ns1.sjdpublishing.com.
sjdpublishing.com.              IN NS   ns2.sjdpublishing.com.
sjdpublishing.com.              IN A    198.38.89.224
ns1.sjdpublishing.com.          IN A    198.38.89.224
ns2.sjdpublishing.com.          IN A    198.38.89.224
```

#### SOA Record for creativeproperty.com.au

```
$TTL    300

@   IN  SOA ns1.sjdpublishing.com. housesboughtfast.hotmail.com. (
            2013090501
            1200
            300
            604800
            3600 )

creativeproperty.com.au.              IN NS   ns1.sjdpublishing.com.
creativeproperty.com.au.              IN NS   ns2.sjdpublishing.com.
creativeproperty.com.au.              IN A    198.38.89.224
www.creativeproperty.com.au.          IN CNAME creativeproperty.com.au.
```

Comment: Will that fix all the above issues?

Comment: It's the largest problem you have currently, you definitely need to start by making sure your glue is correct. I added a link to a youtube video showing how to do it for crazydomains, take a look and report back if it was already done.

Comment: It appears you have host records from your registrar, actually, but it doesn't appear that your nameserver is actually setup to handle the domain sjdpublishing.com, it doesn't return an SOA record, have you created a set of records for sjdpublishing? listing NS records and A records for ns1 and ns2?

Comment: Take a look at the two SOA records I added, be sure you have all of those entries in your nameserver at the very minimum. You didn't mention what nameserver software you are using, so I am assuming bind9. Please note that you should have at least 2 separate servers to run nameservers. It may be less complicated to setup a free zoneedit.com account and point your NS records to their service. I can keep helping you diagnose your nameservers though if you wish to run your own nameserver still.